# jQuery and HTML form not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, passwords

I'm new to JavaScript, HTML and have no knowledge of jQuery. However I am doing an assignment for my class and I need to make a password form. I'd greatly appreciate it if someone can help me out here please.

My code:
(In head of main HTML document):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($){
    $('pass').load('example.html #password');
});
</script>
```

In the example.html:

```
<body>
<div id="password">test123</div>
</body>
```

Body of main HTML document:

```
<form name="login">
Username <input type="text" name="userid"/>
Password <input type="password" name="pswrd"/>
<input type="button" onclick="check(this.form)" value="Login"/>
<input type="reset" value="Cancel"/>
</form>
<script language="javascript">
function check(form)
{
var elem = document.getElementById('pass')
 if(form.userid.value == elem && form.pswrd.value == "pass")
  {
    alert("success!")
  }
 else
 {
   alert("nope") 
  }
}
</script>
```

The problem is, even though the username is "**test123**" and the password is "**pass**", It still alerts "**nope**"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `form.userid.value` is a string. `elem` is a DOM element. They cannot be equal. Did you mean `elem.textContent`?

Comment: Thank you! I added .textContent after `document.getElementById('pass')` and before that I also added `<div id="pass"></div>` So it must fetch the text content pass and then make that the elem. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol If you make that an answer and not a comment I will mark it as approved answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to put `.textContent`after `document.getElementById('pass')`.

Also had to put `<div id="pass"></div>` before all of that.

Comment: exactly, you had to put in an element with ID='pass' before you can do getElementById... you were getting 'nope' because getElementById returned null. try doing console.log(elem) and you would see that an object is now fetched

Answer (score 0):

There is no element by the name 'pass' in your code... There is I'd='password'

May I recommend you check out w3schools.com for more practice

Answer (score 0):

Also, since your JS code is in the head, it may execute before the DOM is loaded. After fixing 'pass' also make sure you use document.ready or place your JS before closing body tag.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding below code satisfies your requirement.

Please enter userid **test123** and password **pass** it will return success otherwise nope.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($){
    $('pass').load('example.html #password');
});
</script>
<script language="javascript">
function check()
{
var userid = document.getElementById('userid').value;
var password = document.getElementById('password').value;

 if(userid == "test123" && password == "pass")
  {
    alert("success!")
  }
 else
 {
   alert("nope") 
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="login">
Username <input type="text" name="userid" id="userid"/>
Password <input type="password" name="pswrd" id="password"/>
<input type="button" onclick="check()" value="Login"/>
<input type="reset" value="Cancel"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I had this previously. The thing is that the username and password is in clear text. accessible to anyone reading the code. I want it to fetch the password from another file and not show the password on my main HTML document. Any way of doing so?